# Problems with connecting series

Tags: highcharts

I can't figure out why I have a gap between series. Here's example http://jsfiddle.net/rsboarder/dbGH7/. The gap is between 10th and 11th April. 
I tried

```
connectNulls: true
```

But that didn't work for me. Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by using two separate series, which can't be connected. Right now multiple colors for one series aren't supported, but will be released in the near future as plugin for Highcharts (~Q3).

Right now what you can do is to add one more point for left or right series, so all series will have one shared point with the same timestamp.

Comment: Yes, I also tried this. But it still looks like a bug. Also am I right supposing that cutted "map" of all chart because of this problem too?

Comment: Why this looks like a bug? Series can't be connected together, no matter what do you set in `connectNulls` and anywhere else :) What "map" you are talking about?

Comment: Like a bug for the user. As for me I understand the problem :) By "map" I mean navigator.

Comment: Navigator is connected always to first series. However, if you want, you can show in navigator separate series. For example concat two series (left and right), and set is as one data in navigator. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series).